# How to prove the functions are bounded?

Tags: functions, proof-explanation

Let f and g be two functions from R to R. Show that if f-g and f+2g are bounded, then both f and g are also bounded. Please Help!!!! How would you prove that these functions are bounded.

Comment: Express $f$ and $g$ in terms of the two given functions and use the triangle inequality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A = {1 \over 3} \begin{bmatrix} 2 & 1 \\ -1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$ and note that
$\|(f,g)^T \| = \|A (f-g,f+2g)^T\| \le  \|A\|  \|(f-g,f+2g)\|$.

Comment: You should take a screenshot of this page and frame it.